Forecasting aggregation throwing error Error in base::colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimension
I am new to forecasting. I am trying to do a hierarchical forecast using the HTS package. I have created two hierarchies. And then I applied below:
forecast_middle_out_lum_arima <- forecast(train_hierarchy_lumpy, h = 7, method = "mo", fmethod = "arima", level = 1)
accuracy(forecast_bottom_up_lum_arima, test_hierarchy_lumpy, levels = 2)

but I keep getting this error:

Error in base::colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) :    'x'
must be an array of at least two dimensions

I am not sure what is happening. My dataset is only for one and I am trying to create a weekly forecast. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?
Code below reproduces the error:
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(hts)
States_df<-c("VIC","TAS","SA~","WA~","NSW","ACT","QLD","NT~")
SKUs<-c("Pro1","Pro2","Pro3","Pro4","Pro5","Pro6")
df_fc<-data.frame(S.no=seq(1,8689),Year=2022,week=sample(1:52,8689,replace = TRUE),state=sample(States_df,8689,replace = TRUE),
              SKU=sample(SKUs,8689,replace = TRUE))
df_fc<-df_fc%>%mutate(Combo=paste(state,SKU,sep = ""))%>%mutate(Sale=sample(10:50,8689,replace=TRUE))
grouped_df_fc<-df_fc%>%group_by(Year,week,Combo)%>%summarise(Qty=sum(Sale,na.rm = TRUE))%>%arrange(Year,week)
pivoted_df_fc<-grouped_df_fc%>%pivot_wider(names_from =Combo,values_from = Qty,values_fill = 0 )
time_series_df_fc<-ts(pivoted_df_fc[,3:50],start = c(2022,1),frequency = 52)
colnames(time_series_df_fc)<-colnames(pivoted_df_fc[,3:50])
hierarchy_df_fc<-hts(time_series_df_fc,characters = c(3,4))
train_hierarchy_df_fc<-window(hierarchy_df_fc,end=c(2022,47))
test_hierarchy_df_fc<-window(hierarchy_df_fc,start=c(2022,48))
forecast_middle_df_fc<-forecast(train_hierarchy_df_fc,h=5,method = "mo",fmethod = "arima",level = 1)
accuracy(forecast_middle_df_fc,test_hierarchy_df_fc,levels = 2)


Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Thank you for responding Sir. I have edited my msg and added a block of code to reproduce the error.

The 'test' that is failing base::colMeans requires an array but you have given it a data.frame. Suggest, at minimum you consider matrices. But pkg author @RobHyndman  is much more qualified to address this.

This is a bug due to there being not enough data to compute the scaling factor in MASE when a seasonal naive method is used (default for seasonal data). I've fixed it in https://github.com/earowang/hts/commit/7e084148990e49955655b9d0f599857fdddd58f4
But I suggest you use the fable package instead of the hts package, which has much better facilities for weekly data, and works with the tidyverse packages. Here is an example using the sample data generated in your question.
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

df_tsibble <- df_fc |>
  group_by(Year, week, state, SKU) |>
  summarise(Qty = sum(Sale, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") |>
  mutate(Week = yearweek(paste0(Year, " W", week))) |>
  select(-Year, -week) |>
  as_tsibble(Week, key = c(state, SKU)) |>
  fill_gaps()

train_tsibble <- df_tsibble |>
  filter(Week <= yearweek("2022 W47"))

fable_df_fc <- train_tsibble |>
  aggregate_key(state * SKU, Qty = sum(Qty)) |>
  model(arima = ARIMA(Qty)) |>
  reconcile(mint = min_trace(arima)) |>
  forecast(h = 5)

fable_acc <- accuracy(fable_df_fc, df_tsibble, measures = list(rmse = RMSE, mae = MAE))
#> Warning: The future dataset is incomplete, incomplete out-of-sample data will be treated as missing. 
#> 5 observations are missing between 2022 W48 and 2022 W52
fable_acc |> filter(SKU == "Pro1")
#> # A tibble: 18 × 6
#> Loading required namespace: crayon
#>    .model state        SKU    .type  rmse   mae
#>    <chr>  <chr*>       <chr*> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 arima  ACT          Pro1   Test   51.9  42.4
#>  2 arima  NSW          Pro1   Test   51.8  43.5
#>  3 arima  NT~          Pro1   Test   51.3  45.9
#>  4 arima  QLD          Pro1   Test   66.9  59.5
#>  5 arima  SA~          Pro1   Test   44.5  39.1
#>  6 arima  TAS          Pro1   Test   52.4  50.2
#>  7 arima  VIC          Pro1   Test   59.0  44.5
#>  8 arima  WA~          Pro1   Test   35.4  26.8
#>  9 arima  <aggregated> Pro1   Test  NaN   NaN  
#> 10 mint   ACT          Pro1   Test   52.2  43.2
#> 11 mint   NSW          Pro1   Test   51.2  42.0
#> 12 mint   NT~          Pro1   Test   53.0  48.5
#> 13 mint   QLD          Pro1   Test   67.3  59.7
#> 14 mint   SA~          Pro1   Test   43.9  38.8
#> 15 mint   TAS          Pro1   Test   49.0  46.2
#> 16 mint   VIC          Pro1   Test   60.9  47.4
#> 17 mint   WA~          Pro1   Test   35.1  26.6
#> 18 mint   <aggregated> Pro1   Test  NaN   NaN

Created on 2024-12-25 with reprex v2.1.1
BTW, you can't actually use middle-out with this example because it is not hierarchical. Your hts example has assumed SKU is nested within State, which it obviously isn't. In any case, minimum trace reconciliation will usually give you much better results. So that's what I've used in the code above.
